# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78' - Error when I pass 2 parameters (ASP/MSSQL)

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic, parameters, recordset

My classic ASP page thorws up an error when I pass 2 paremeters to the Exec code for my 
stored procedure. Basically I want to send 1 paremeter to cover the column I am looking for
and one for the search-term. For example imSchool, New York University. I have data checks on the data sent as well as Record Set.State code showing that everytime i choose SQL Query with the two paramerts the error "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed." always shows. 
I tried to open the object at " While Not rs.EOF" line of code where it error out bit no luck.
I am thinking my SQLQuery is bad because when I run the Stored Procedure in MSSQL with the same input I get a return table everytime. SQL Server 2008 R2 and Classic ASP.

HERE IS MY IF STATMENT WITH SQLQUERY CODE (keep in mind the 1st one works fine and data is selected from the DB)

```
    SQLQuery = "Exec sp_vw_InternImport"

    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorType = 3

    rs.Open SQLQuery, OBJdbConnection


    If filterColmn <> "" Then

    SQlQuery = "Exec sp_vw_InternImport_ColID @LookUpID=N'" + filterID + "'" + ", @LookUpCol=N'" + filterID + "'"

    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorType = 3

    rs.Open SQLQuery, OBJdbConnection

    End If
```

HERE IS MY STORED PROCEDURE CODE

```
          SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
             GO

           ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_vw_InternImport_ColID]
            (
            @LookUpID nvarchar (255),
            @LookUpCol nvarchar (50)
            )

          AS 
       SET NOCOUNT ON
       BEGIN 

        IF @LookUpCol = 'imYear'
        SELECT * FROM v_InternImport WHERE imYear = @LookUpID

ELSE
IF @LookUpCol = 'imSchool'
SELECT * FROM v_InternImport WHERE imSchool = @LookUpID

ELSE
IF @LookUpCol = 'imDiscipline'
SELECT * FROM v_InternImport WHERE imDiscipline = @LookUpID

       IF @LookUpCol = 'imDegree'
       SELECT * FROM v_InternImport WHERE imDegree = @LookUpID
       END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing arguments to stored procedure directly, you don't have to "assign" the parameters. Doing this probably results in the whole value passed (e.g. `@LookUpCol` will have the value of `@LookUpCol ='imYear'`) thus your SP won't select anything and you have empty and closed recordset.

Try having such code instead:

```
SQlQuery = "Exec sp_vw_InternImport_ColID '" & filterID & "', '" & filterID & "'"
```

Comment: This worked thanks again. The previous answer is a concern as well but I close my recordset at the bottom of the page and therefore it remains closed before it gets to the second IF statement.

Comment: Cheers, to have best practice code look into the ADODB.Command object and use it, creating the parameters instead of passing them as raw text - what you have is fine and should not be vulnerable to SQL injection but still not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same object twice at the same time (like `rs`), you have to make it another name or you have to close it and start over.. This should work:

```
SQLQuery = "Exec sp_vw_InternImport"
If filterColmn <> "" Then SQLQuery = "Exec sp_vw_InternImport_ColID @LookUpID=N'" + filterID + "'" + ", @LookUpCol=N'" + filterID + "'"

  Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  rs.CursorType = 3
  rs.Open SQLQuery, OBJdbConnection
  rs.Close
```

Or in your example, if you close the first `rs` object before you go on to the next, it may help.

`set rs = nothing   ... then .... set rs = server.createobject`

So like this:

```
SQLQuery = "Exec sp_vw_InternImport"

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorType = 3
rs.Open SQLQuery, OBJdbConnection

rs.Close ------ Close it before you re-open it

If filterColmn <> "" Then

SQlQuery = "Exec sp_vw_InternImport_ColID @LookUpID=N'" + filterID + "'" + ", @LookUpCol=N'" + filterID + "'"

rs.Open SQLQuery, OBJdbConnection
rs.Close ------ Always Close your Objects!

End If
```